# Close Ktor socket server without referencing all accepted connections

Tags: kotlin, sockets, server, ktor

Is there a way to stop a Ktor socket server without explicitly tracking all the accepted connections?

This is my simple server code, which I removed all the unrelated stuff:

```kotlin
// TcpServer.kt

private fun accept() {
    // 'controller' is an instance of my own class, which keeps a reference
    // to the corresponding SelectorManager and ServerSocket.
    controller.selector.launch(Dispatchers.IO + this.acceptFailureHandler) {
        val socket = controller.serverSocket.accept()

        controller.selector.launch(Dispatchers.Default + this@TcpServer.postAcceptFailureHandler) {
            // If I don't track the accepted socket in
            // this method, I won't be able to close it later.
            this@TcpServer.onAccepted(socket)
        }
    }
}

fun stop() {
    // Trying to clean everything, but it doesn't seem to work. The server stopped
    // listening to new connections, but the accepted ones are still there.
    runCatching {
        controller.selector.use {
            runCatching {
                controller.serverSocket.use {
                }
            }
            // After socket closing, stop all suspending tasks.
            runCatching {
                controller.selector?.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to cancel the coroutine scope where the server socket is bound?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman That SelectorManager itself is the coroutine scope I used to create this ServerSocket:
 val selector = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO + this.selectFailureHandler)

selector.launch(Dispatchers.IO + this.bindFailureHandler) {

        val serverSocket = aSocket(selector).tcp().bind(serverAddress, port)

}